# array.push() builds array, but array indices are undefinded

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

So I am working with a list of objects to build an array of values in JavaScript, but for some reason it is building a list of keys with values. It seems like I am doing it correctly.

Original Data:

```
"features" : [
    {
      "attributes" : {
        "vehicle_id" : 2077, 
        "cleaning_time" : 1588198260000
      }, 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "x" : 0, 
        "y" : 0
      }
    }, 
    {
      "attributes" : {
        "vehicle_id" : 2071, 
        "cleaning_time" : 1588258620000
      }, 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "x" : 0, 
        "y" : 0
      }
    },
```

Building the Array:

```
let list = [];
for(let item in features){
    let date = new Date(features[item].attributes.cleaning_time)
    if((new Date() - date) < 7200000){
        console.log(features[item].attributes.vehicle_id);
        let veh = features[item].attributes.vehicle_id
        list.push(veh);
    }
}
```

Final Array:

```
    []
​
0: 6618
​
1: 2204
​
2: 2204
​
3: 6618
​
4: 2204
​
5: 2204
​
length: 6
​
<prototype>: Array []
app.js:176:11
```

EDIT: 
This data is joining to another data source below is the function that is being used to join in based on the vehicle_id.

Joining List to another data source:

```
for(let i in data){
    let veh = data[i].vehicle.vehicle.id;
    data[i].vehicle.isClean = list.includes(veh);
}
```

This script is meant to filter through data that is less than 2 hours hold. This script runs every 15 seconds and is reevaluates the data everytime.

Comment: Its not keys, its the indexes of the array that you see in console

Comment: then why does list[0] == undefined?

Comment: I think the first line should be `let features = [` ... rather than just `"features": [` ...  It would sure help if you make it a runnable snippet so that little things like this are caught by you instead of by us.

Comment: The output did not come from the input you provided.  Also, don't make the example dependent on the actual date - that makes it flaky.  Replace `new Date()` with an actual fixed date.

Comment: @Wyck I am trying to get it to tell me if the entry is over 2 hours hold. How would I not use new Date() with a fixed time. This script runs every 15 seconds.

Comment: First, you need to assign your data to some variable in order to use it in the script. You cannot use `features` as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly as best I can tell. Based on a comment I have adjusted the code.

```js
let list = [];
var features = [
    {
      "attributes" : {
        "vehicle_id" : 2077, 
        "cleaning_time" : new Date() - 100
      }, 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "x" : 0, 
        "y" : 0
      }
    }, 
    {
      "attributes" : {
        "vehicle_id" : 2071, 
        "cleaning_time" : new Date() - 100
      }, 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "x" : 0, 
        "y" : 0
      }
    }
]
for(let item in features){
    console.log(item)
    let date = new Date(features[item].attributes.cleaning_time)
    console.log(`(new Date() - date) < 7200000 is ${(new Date() - date) < 7200000}`)
    if((new Date() - date) < 7200000){
        console.log(features[item].attributes.vehicle_id);
        let veh = features[item].attributes.vehicle_id
        list.push(veh)
    }
}
console.log(`list[0] == undefined is ${list[0] == undefined}`)
```

Comment: Sorry, but the data is a part of an on going survey and it is mean to filter entries that are over 2 hours old. those 2 entries were some of the first submitted so they would not return True. The final array that I included is mean to show that  it passes.

Comment: With your original data structure `features[item]` is `undefined`. So `list[0]` is `undefined` too. It's not because of `.push()`.